# Invalid object name even though the object is valid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unit-testing

I have a unit test for a controllers actionresult. When I run the unit test it breaks at `db.SaveChanges();` part of the action result. When I test the actual method (via web brower and data in database) it is fine however when I run my unit test it fails. The error I am receiving is: DbUpdateException was unhandled by user code. See inner exception, Inner Exception: `{"Invalid object name 'dbo.Projects'."}`
I am using entityframeworks codefirst structure and here is my code:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorize(Roles = "A")]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult AddProject(Projects project)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      using (var db = new MyDbContext())
      {
         db.ProjectModels.Add(project);
         db.SaveChanges();
      }
      return RedirectToAction("ListOfProjects", "Project");
   }
   return View(project);
}


[TestMethod()]
public void AddProjectTestWithModl()
{
    var controller = new AdminController();
    var model = new Projects() { Name = "Name", Description = "Desc", Duration = "1 month" };
    var result = controller.AddProject(model) as ViewResult;
    Assert.AreEqual(model, result.ViewData.Model);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invalid object name 'dbo.Projects'. is an exception from sql server. It means your table does not exist in the dbo schema.

Check that you are connected to the correct database and that migrations have been run.

Comment: This does exist in my database, and the schema is correct. If I breakpoint through the controllers actionresult method it works fine only when I run the unit test does it give that error. I have the feeling the unit test or EF is doing something to my dbcontext model maybe?

Comment: Check the connection string in app.config in the test project